# CloudWatch - alerting on target down ONLY when certain tag is attached to the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi all :D hope you are well.

So I am trying to set up an alert in CloudWatch that will fire when a target from a target group is down.
This step I have achieved.
The issue is that some times, I wish to do some maintenance on one of the targets and the alert still fires. For other alerting services we use, we use a tag with an condition "if monitored == true then".
Is there a way of applying the same or similar in CloudWatch?

I was wondering maybe a composite alarm could do, but there is no tag metric.
And it does not seem to allow adding conditions to alerts.

Thanks.